# Create an unprivilleged user in android

Tags: multi-user, accounts

I want to create an account for android that cannot create another user or remove apps installed by the device owner.

I have looked at creating other accounts or logging as guest and that gives the user an opportunity to install and remove apps.

Does android enable one to have a none admin like account where a user cannot install or remove apps and cannot create accounts?

Comment: The answer below by Reddy is accurate however, Android does support "dedicated devices" by way of APIs that let developers restrict how devices work through device policy controller (DPC) protocols.  Often called "kiosk mode" - these are typically custom launchers where the device must be _fully managed_ which allows for the support of Ephemeral Users.  An example of this is Samsung's "kids mode" launcher app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does android enable one to have a none admin like account where a user cannot install or remove apps and cannot create accounts?

No. Secondary users can install and remove apps and create accounts.
From [Supporting Multiple Users](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user):

> Account. Accounts are contained within a user but are not defined by a user, nor is a user defined by or linked to any given account. Users and profiles contain their own unique accounts but are not required to have accounts to be functional. The list of accounts differs by user.

And:

> When employing multiple users on an Android device, keep the following behavior in mind:
>
> - Notifications appear for all accounts of a single user at once.
> - Notifications for other users do not appear until active.
> - Each user gets a workspace to install and place apps.
> - No user has access to the app data of another user.
> - Any user can affect the installed apps for all users.
> - The primary user can remove apps or even the entire workspace established by secondary users.